# Clojure Noir Json Put

Tags: json, clojure, put, noir

I'm working through the tutorial [Mark McGranaghan REST Tutorial](http://mmcgrana.github.com/2010/08/clojure-rest-api.html) however I'm trying to do it using Noir instead.

I can add new items, however it never takes the body of the PUT command.

I think the problem with how I'm trying to construct the put statement.  I'm thinking the {:keys [id attrs]} is the issue, because I'm trying to tell it the json content is in the url, when its not, its in the body.  Can anyone advise how i retrieve it from the body using noirs defpage?

(put is in a separate elem file)

```
(defn put [id attrs]
  (let [new-attrs (merge (get id) attrs)]
  (swap! elems assoc id new-attrs)
  new-attrs))

(defpage [:put "/elems/:id"] {:keys [id attrs]}
  (json-response (elem/put id attrs)))
```

Comment: Which version of noir are you using?

Comment: If this is still a problem for you and you have a gist of this lying around I could probably take a crack at it... I have a feeling this is a pretty specific problem...

Comment: I ended up doing it with straight compojure, So I'm working with that now.  If i do tackle it again in noir ill update this question.

Comment: @Dale you should probably answer and accept your own question so if someone lands here in the future at least they have one possible solution

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing "attrs=somevalue" in the post then that will work, but if you are trying to capture all the key-value pairs, this works for me in 1.3.0-beta1:

```
(defpage [:put "/elems/:id"] attrs 
  (response/json {:attrs attrs}))
```

then:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d "foo=bar" http://localhost:8080/elems/123
=> {"attrs":{"id":"123","foo":"bar"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Chris Granger's JSON-parsing middleware function from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clj-noir/INqvBo6oXIA/discussion), and use it as described [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clj-noir/11ahzz6n7q/noir-post-json-data) to receive JSON data.

in your case it'll look like

```
(defpage [:put "/elems/:id"] {{:keys [attr1 attr2 attr3]} :backbone }
         "OK")
```

But you just need to add that "backbone" (I personally renamed it to "json-params") middleware first.

Answer (score 0):

So these are form parameters? If so, destructuring params like you did here should work just fine. You can get the whole request inside the defpage using `noir.request`. I'd take at look at that and see what it contains. It should clarify things significantly.